# How to approach a regression problem?

Tags: machine-learning, data-visualization, data-mining, dataset, exploratory-data-analysis

I have to solve a regression problem involving 302 variables.

How do we select appropriate models or ensemble of models to work well ?

Does this decision of choosing models come from the ideas obtained by Exploratory Data Analysis or by trial method ?

This is the problem from Kaggle that I have to solve:

https://www.kaggle.com/c/liberty-mutual-fire-peril

Comment: Selecting a model is a huge topic--witness the number of questions here tagged with [tag:model-selection], for instance. Please review some of those questions to see how others have focused their questions on narrower, objectively answerable issues.  That might show you how to edit your question constructively.

Answer (score 0):

Hi what I understand is you are trying to predict/ regress something using 302 variables.

Using all these variable at single time is for regression is a bad idea.

So what you can do is
  1) find out variable importance of each variable using random forest and then selecting highest 50-100 variables.

2)Then use these selected variables in your regression model and then apply n fold cross validation (CV) to find out error. Eg 1 st you can take 60 variables with high variable importance value and apply n-fold CV. Then take 75 variables (high variable importance) and apply CV. 
3) Compare the error you got in step 2 (i.e. error with 60 and then 75 variables)
like 60,70 you can try other no of variables (50 or 40)
4)Select number variables (from above step) which give you list error.

5) To avoid over fitting try 5 fold, 4 fold cv which will give you better estimate of error.Also you can try regularization to penalize sources of over fitting.

Comment: You still risk overfitting by not including your entire process in the cross-validation.

Comment: OOB-CV for variable selection (e.g. R randomForest::rfcv) and wrap it all up in a outer CV